# Multivariate limit of $|x|^{|y|}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to prove that the limit:

$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}|x|^{|y|}=1$

I started with
   $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}{|x|^{|y|}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}{e^{|y|ln|x|}}=e^{\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}{|y|ln|x|}}$

And then tried substituting $x=r\sin{\theta}$ and $y=r\cos{\theta}$ to get:

$e^{\lim_{r\to 0}{|r\cos{\theta}|ln|r\sin{\theta}|}}$

However, as I'm trying to use the squeeze theorem, I can't figure out a lower bound that would work on this. Any suggestions? Does the limit even exist?

Comment: See my answer to [Multivariable limits](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/1891/745).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This limit doesn't exist. Consider two different paths $y=0$ and $x=0$. One leads to $0$-limit and the other to $1$-limit. The figure below shows why:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The limit does not exist: When approaching $(0,0)$ along the $x$ axis we have $|x|^{|y|}=|x|^0=1$, while when approaching along the $y$ axis we have $|x|^{|y|}=0^{|y|}=0$.